# Is there an easy way to stack divs for mobile and tablet plus keep them centered?

Tags: html, css

I've got a container with some divs which make 3 boxes display horizontally.

I am trying to get the divs to stack vertically (centered) on mobile and tablets. The problem I'm having is the media queries and styles I'm using don't seem to be working properly.

```
<div class="container-2">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-compact-disc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Artists</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nam quae quasi enim, praesentium, deserunt voluptatibus dolores laboriosam ex odio quod aperiam ipsa aspernatur soluta suscipit et iusto quas impedit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Calendar</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nam quae quasi enim, praesentium, deserunt voluptatibus dolores laboriosam ex odio quod aperiam ipsa aspernatur soluta suscipit et iusto quas impedit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Contact Us</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nam quae quasi enim, praesentium, deserunt voluptatibus dolores laboriosam ex odio quod aperiam ipsa aspernatur soluta suscipit et iusto quas impedit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.container-2 .box {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(400px - 30px);
  height: calc(350px - 30px);
  background: #0000005b;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The 3 divs (they are the boxes) will go from horizontal to vertical when on mobile and tablet plus center themselves.

Any pointers on the best way to align/move divs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) is going to be your friend here-- you change the `flex-direction` at your breakpoint and tweak the flex settings:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.inner {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .inner {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped put me on track big time. I ended up not using a media query but it's still responsive...

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox will make this task significantly easier. A link to the Codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/jaredforth/pen/gEJxdo).

A rough version of your HTML and CSS are as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-2">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-compact-disc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Artists</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nam quae quasi enim, praesentium, deserunt voluptatibus dolores laboriosam ex odio quod aperiam ipsa aspernatur soluta suscipit et iusto quas impedit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Calendar</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nam quae quasi enim, praesentium, deserunt voluptatibus dolores laboriosam ex odio quod aperiam ipsa aspernatur soluta suscipit et iusto quas impedit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Contact Us</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nam quae quasi enim, praesentium, deserunt voluptatibus dolores laboriosam ex odio quod aperiam ipsa aspernatur soluta suscipit et iusto quas impedit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.container-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container-2 .box {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(400px - 30px);
  height: calc(350px - 30px);
  background: #0000005b;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .container-2 {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 70vw;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your CSS to switch on tablet `768px` to stack the way you asked for (`width: 90%` with left/right margin of 5%). However I would take a different approach. I'm absolutely not happy with your fixed widths. I didn't want to rework your whole CSS and markup to something that might not fit your needs so I added just the `@media` queries to answer your question. I would go for a flex based approach or at least some percentage based widths depending what you are looking for.

```css
.container-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.container-2 .box {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(400px - 30px);
  height: calc(350px - 30px);
  background: #0000005b;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container-2 .box {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 15px 5%;
  }
  .container-2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-2">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-compact-disc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Artists</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nam quae quasi enim, praesentium, deserunt voluptatibus dolores laboriosam ex odio quod aperiam ipsa aspernatur soluta suscipit et iusto quas impedit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Calendar</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nam quae quasi enim, praesentium, deserunt voluptatibus dolores laboriosam ex odio quod aperiam ipsa aspernatur soluta suscipit et iusto quas impedit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Contact Us</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, nam quae quasi enim, praesentium, deserunt voluptatibus dolores laboriosam ex odio quod aperiam ipsa aspernatur soluta suscipit et iusto quas impedit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update: If you want to stop that unpretty overflow from happening during shrink use in the media query a value of roughly `1200px`. But I still highly recommend a better approach.

Comment: I removed the fixed width and it's working perfectly....why don't you use fixed widths ever?

Comment: @soccer_mullet you can used fixed widths but you have to handle the breaking points properly  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using media query and flex container.